# Vaadin OptionGroup set width only for one checkbox

Tags: java, css, checkbox, vaadin, vaadin6

I have OptionGroup component and many checkboxes in there.
I want to change width (or another css property) on only one checkbox.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be not possible with the current Vaadin API (7.6.6) but there is an [add-on FlexibleOptionGroup](https://vaadin.com/directory/#!addon/flexibleoptiongroup) which supports individual items. If your item in the `OptionGroup` is at a fixed position, you could use n-th element selector of CSS to change its style. The [Valo theme demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!checkboxes) shows an `OptionGroup` with explicit width, maybe this fits in your case.